# MySQL: In PHP, a DELETE statement will replace some values with NULL instead of deleting

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in my database I'm trying to delete a row from.

When I use the query `DELETE FROM Exercises WHERE id = 2` in PHP, it simply ends up setting the `exercise_name` variable to `NULL`, and the `submission_deadline` variable to `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`, leaving every other field fully intact (probably because the other fields are explicitly defined as "NOT NULL".

The weirdest thing, is that when I literally use the same, copied and pasted query in console, the row gets properly removed. In both cases, I'm logged in as root in MySQL, so permissions shouldn't be a problem.

Here's the table in my database I'm trying to delete a row from:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Exercises`;

CREATE TABLE `Exercises` (
  `id` INTEGER NULL AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Unique ID of this exercise',
  `exercise_name` MEDIUMTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Descriptive name of this exercise',
  `default_state_data` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL COMMENT 'The default state data for this exercise',
  `solution_data` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL COMMENT 'Example solution for this exercise.',
  `solution_gate` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL COMMENT 'The label of the gate that will be compared',
  `submission_deadline` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '9999-12-31 23:59:59' COMMENT 'Deadline for the submission of answers to this exercise',

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) COMMENT 'All logic gate exercises';
```

NOTE: In case that matters, the above "id" is referenced as a foreign key in two other places.

For testing purposes, I populate it with two rows, as follows:

```
INSERT INTO `Exercises` (`exercise_name`,`submission_deadline`, `default_state_data`, `solution_gate`, `solution_data`) VALUES
('Logic Gate Playground','2016-03-30 23:59:59', '<massive json object>', 'S_OR', '<massive json object>');
INSERT INTO `Exercises` (`exercise_name`,`submission_deadline`, `default_state_data`, `solution_gate`, `solution_data`) VALUES
('Building with NAND','2016-04-07 23:59:59', '<massive json object>', 'XNOR', '<massive json object>');
```

An excerpt of the PHP code I'm using to delete a row from this table:

```
$exercise_id = intval($_POST['exercise_id']);
// Let's remove the exercise with a prepared statement
$prepared_statement = $mysql_connection->prepare("DELETE FROM Exercises WHERE id = ?");
$prepared_statement->bind_param("i", $exercise_id);
$result = $prepared_statement->execute();
```

Also, after that failed, I tried a simpler version of the above to test if that would work (it didn't):

```
$exercise_id = intval($_POST['exercise_id']);
// Let's remove the exercise
$result = mysqli_query($mysql_connection, "DELETE FROM Exercises WHERE id = {$exercise_id}");
```

I also tried adding single quotation marks around the variable I'm inputting.

At this point, I'm at a complete loss. Does anyone have any insight into why this would possibly be happening?

**EDIT:**

When I replaced the entire PHP file with the following, it worked and deleted the entire row properly):

```
<?php
require_once '../includes/database-connect.php';
mysqli_query($mysql_connection, "DELETE FROM Exercises WHERE id = 2");
```

That still leaves me wondering why my original file doesn't work. Here's the entire file (that doesn't work):

```
<?php
require_once '../includes/database-connect.php';
require_once '../includes/functions.php';
$_SESSION['user_id'] = 'adm12345'; // TODO Remove debug line
// Check if the mysql connection is established
if (!$mysql_connection) {
    echo "<b>Failed to connect to MySQL database; MySQL error below:</b><br><pre><code>".mysqli_error($mysql_connection)."</code></pre>";
}
// Retrieve the user ID from the session
$user_id = check_login($mysql_connection, TRUE);
if ($user_id) {
    // User is logged in as an admin
    $exercise_id = intval($_POST['exercise_id']);
    // Let's remove the exercise with a prepared statement
    $prepared_statement = $mysql_connection->prepare("DELETE FROM Exercises WHERE id = ?");
    $prepared_statement->bind_param("i", $exercise_id);
    $result = $prepared_statement->execute();
    if ($result) {
        echo 1;
    } else {
        $error = mysqli_error($mysql_connection);
        if ($error) {
            echo "<b>Failed to submit to server; MySQL error below:</b><br><pre>" . mysqli_error($mysql_connection) . "</pre>";
        } else {
            echo "<b>Failed to submit to server even though MySQL did not throw an error.</b>";
        }
    }
} else {
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        echo "<b>You are not an admin, you cannot delete exercises.</b>";
    } else {
        echo "<b>You're not logged in.</b>";
    }
}
```

Comment: What goes in $_POST['exercise_id']? What if you var_dump your statement?

Comment: @MathieudeLorimier It is an int. It really doesn't matter. I replaced `$mysql_connection->prepare("DELETE FROM Exercises WHERE id = ?");` with `$mysql_connection->prepare("DELETE FROM Exercises WHERE id = 2");` and it gave me the same result anyway (same thing with single quotation marks around the 2). Either way, the intended row does get affected (name is null, and deadline is '0000-00-00 00:00:00'), just not removed.

Comment: Why is the `default` for `id` `null`? when you show/browse the table, what's the data you inserted look like?

Comment: It is unlikely that this is the result of the delete query. I would say your php code does sg else to insert the rows back or you have a trigger that interferes with the delete.

Comment: @Jon The ID is auto incremented. Nonetheless, here's the table (screenshot from PhpStorm) before I "deleted" in PHP: http://i.imgur.com/xVupo6h.png, and here it is after I "deleted" in PHP: http://i.imgur.com/cj9QX5r.png

Comment: @Shadow I agree, that would be quite unlikely behaviour. can you provide with php and mysql versions? Also, what happens if you create a php file with just the  DELETE FROM Exercises WHERE id = 2 query?

Comment: @Shadow 1. The PHP code I wrote does nothing else to the database when deleting the table. 2. Triggers or not, why would the exact same command work in the console but not through PHP?

Comment: @grseko I didn't really think it'd matter, I was more curious. It is odd that it leaves the `id` field alone as well.

Comment: @MathieudeLorimier I created the file with only a query to delete, and... it worked. I'm not sure how that worked, but the whole file doesn't. I'll edit the entire php file content into my question, once I do, can you tell me how that's possible?

Comment: To tell you how that's possible, we'd need to see all your php that gets run to see how it fails in that file.

Comment: @Jon I edited the question to include the entire file.

Comment: @MathieudeLorimier I edited the question to include the entire file

Comment: I'm willing to bet your princess is in another castle and that one of the include files or functions you're calling is making the change. If you don't feel like scouring the code I would do some select queries at various points in the code for the table in question and print_r the results. This way you can see when the change is made and track it down.

Comment: @mikealeonetti You're probably right. I've been re-reading the code over and over again and I cannot see any logical reason why it wouldn't work. I'll look in other places tomorrow though, as it's late for me and I spent way too long on this. I'm definitely closer to figuring it out now than before I asked the question. I would mark some of these comments as helpful, but apparently I don't have reputation high enough for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DELETE statement, if successful deletes data. If unsuccessful it does not change the data. It does not update values to null. If you are seeing null values after issuing a DELETE statement, the fault is in the code you are reading those values back with.

Comment: The fault was actually in my AJAX request. All these problems caused by a stupid, embarrassing omission. instead of calling the "delete-exercise.php", I was calling "update-exercise.php" because I forgot to change this after copying and pasting the ajax code...